# @Transactional Deprecated with Play 2.7

Tags: java, hibernate, playframework

Since @Transactional is depcrecated with play 2.7, how do I upgrade my code to make entity manager Transactional.

Answer (score 0):

According to [play documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/JavaJPA#Running-JPA-transactions) `JPAApi.withTransaction` is what you need:

```
public CompletionStage<Long> runningWithTransaction() {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        // lambda is an instance of Function<EntityManager, Long>
        return jpaApi.withTransaction(entityManager -> {
            Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("select max(age) from people");
            return (Long) query.getSingleResult();
        });
    }, executionContext);
}
```